# Jquery - onclick event - div content reflection

Tags: jquery, html, reflection, svg

is there any simple / not-so-simple way of achieving such solution, that after click on hyperlink, some div content will be reflected?

Please, take a look on my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/V44tS/2/

I use such code

```
$("#reflect-content").click(function() {
$('.container').css('-webkit-transform','scaleX(-1)');
$('.container').css('-moz-transform','scaleX(-1)');
$('.container').css('-o-transform','scaleX(-1)');
$('.container').css('-ms-transform','scaleX(-1)');
$('.container').css('transform','scaleX(-1)');
});
```

I know that pasting SVG content just like that is probably not the smartest way, but this is how my clients system generate the code..

The only thing is that - after one reflection, action stops. how to make it in a loop so after each click, it will reflect it?

thanks for any tips!

best,
Pawel

Comment: Do you want to rotate it or make a mirror reflection..?

Comment: I want to achieve reflection

Comment: Create a CSS class with the styles you want then just toggle the class on click like this: http://jsfiddle.net/V44tS/3/

Comment: Did the same as @Joe did... Difference is he was smart to use `scaleX` and I sticked to `scaleY`... http://jsfiddle.net/V44tS/4/

Comment: sometimes the easiest, is the hardest :) thanks Guys!

Answer (score 1):

First you may add a new style element that define those CSS properties for the class container.

```
<style>
  .containerReflected
  {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
</style>
```

Then apply this class to elements with class container.

```
$('.container').addClass("containerReflected");
```